# common meanings of "I've got it"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What are the possible meanings of "I've got it"? As far as I know, it may mean possession like here:

> – Jack you also need to have a backpack if you want to go with us.
>
> – Well, **I've got it**.

Here Jack reports his possession of a backpack.

Also, as I can tell from my Google research, it may mean the possession of some non-physical things like ideas or infections:

> – **I've got it!** We will go by train instead!

> – Now I know for sure that **I've got it**, too. Doctors completed the test and it came back positive.

But are there any other meanings that this phrase may usually convey?

Please, note that I mean exactly the phrase "I've got it." (not "I got it", "I get it", "I've gotten it", "I've got it all", "I've got it down", etc.)

Comment: "I've got" is not really important here. The meanings are all different because "it" is a pronoun that is referring to different things in all your examples.

Comment: The meanings of *get* are different in each example, too. Most of the meanings of *get* can be used with a first person singular subject and a verb in that tense, too.

Comment: Jack would say "I've got _one_" He would only use _it_ to refer to a particular backpack that had already been mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example - "Well, I've got it" the emphasis would be on "got". But if someone had asked, "Who's got Jack's backpack?" Jack might have replied "**I've** got it". The emphasis here would be on "I've".

In a different context it's also possible to emphasize "it". "I've got **'it**" means "I've got sex appeal." [Definition 8 at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/it).] This derives from an actress - Clara Bow - who became known as "the 'It' girl" after appearing in the film of a book named "It".